# Concerning Using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For the purpose of testing, this is the code I'm using on my regular expression:

```
<?php
function handlePhone($p) {
    return preg_replace("[^0-9xX\+]", "", $p);
}

echo handlePhone("+44(324)-s123-32yousuck42x123");
?>
```

Right now, all that's printing is that exact string as if no changes were made. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use delimiters at the end and begining of your pattern, example with `/`:

```
function handlePhone($p) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9xX\+]/", "", $p);
}
```

Note that you can use other delimiters: `~` `#` `@` ...

Comment: That works, thanks. Now, if I were to have a longer regex, would I need those around the entire pattern as a whole, or around any []'s and such?

Comment: @TheBlab: delimiters are for the whole pattern, more info here: www.regular-expressions.info